# brew install GnuPG. doesn't work, am I missing something?

Tags: homebrew

I'm using a MacBook with macOS Monterey Version 12.1

I'm doing a. simple `brew install gnupg` as shown here:

https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/gnupg

I've done `brew install gnupg2`. with the same results.  I can't seem to find a solution online.  This is the closest but it's not close enough. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62202633/high-sierra-and-homebrew-not-playing-nice-for-gpg

This is my error:

```
pete@petes-Air pbk_app % brew install gnupg
Warning: No available formula with the name "gnupg".
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

Comment: Works here. Might help to run `brew doctor` and fix any brew-related issues reported.

Comment: @nohillside thanks!  after running that it told me that homebrew wasn't tapped correctly so I reinstalled it!

Comment: Is this on M1 (OS: 12.4) ?